# Not able to insert text message in sent folder

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am creating a Messanger Application in android to deal with sms.

Here after sending the sms, i am using this code to add that message in sent folder.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("address", number);
values.put("body", desc); 

getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

This code works perfectly in my Lenevo phone, but not working in Xiaomi Phones.
Will some one help me to tackle the bug???

Comment: What versions of Android are the phones running?

Comment: in Xiaomi its 4.4 and in Lenevo it was lolipop

Comment: Is your app the default SMS app?

Comment: yes ..i did it.Even it wont work

Comment: Well, it should work, if your app is the default. You might try changing the Uri to just `"content://sms"`, and adding a value of `2` for the `"type"`.

Comment: tried that also...no progress

Comment: Dunno. Maybe Xiaomi doesn't use the standard Provider and methods. Are you getting any warnings or errors in the logcat? Can you delete a message? Do other third-party SMS apps work correctly on that device?

Comment: This should work. Bcz i have seen on a "Drizzle Sms" and this feature worked there

Comment: OK, what about the other two questions?

Comment: ya..I can delete the sms and other third party apps are working perfectly

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the logcat? The only thing I can think of, provided everything else is correct, is that you're missing some values that might be required by Xiaomi's Provider implementation. E.g., the `"date"` column.

Comment: no error in log....I dont know why this happening